# Display Log with desired notation in output

Tags: output-formatting, customization

I wish to display logarithms with different bases in the single-term rather than numerator/denominator form during output:

```
Log[17]/Log[2]   ->  Log2[17]
Log[13]/Log[10]  ->  Log10[13]
Log[99]/Log[11]  ->  Log[11, 99]
```

What is the best way to apply formatting rules like this?

Comment: Note: this Q&A is intended both to instruct and to solicit alternative methods or refinements of methods shown.

Comment: Wouldn't a requirement to have all output in the *same base (that you globally set)* be a more natural one? So that `Log10[2] + Log[5]` automatically converts to `1/Log2[10] + Log2[5]/Log2[E]` if you're a CS person?

Comment: @Sjoerd again that's not what I'm going for here but feel free to post an answer to that effect if you want. :-)

Comment: Never had that requirement, so that would go against the FAQ (asking questions about problems you actually face).  :-P

Comment: Well, `Log[17]/Log[2]` *is a problem I actually face*: seeing that kind of output annoys me as I compulsively want to shorten it. :^)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One can use [`$PrePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$PrePrint.html) and [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) to effect this:

```
$PrePrint = # /. {
     Log[n_]/Log[2]  :> Defer @ Log2[n],
     Log[n_]/Log[10] :> Defer @ Log10[n],
     Log[n_]/Log[b_] :> Defer @ Log[b, n]
     } &;
```

Or [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes.html):

```
MakeBoxes[Log[n_]/Log[2], fmt_]  := ToBoxes[Defer @ Log2[n], fmt]
MakeBoxes[Log[n_]/Log[10], fmt_] := ToBoxes[Defer @ Log10[n], fmt]
MakeBoxes[Log[n_]/Log[b_], fmt_] := ToBoxes[Defer @ Log[b, n], fmt]
```

It is also possible to use [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) but in this case it requires unprotecting [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html):

```
Unprotect[Times];

Format[Log[n_]/Log[2]]  := Defer @ Log2[n]
Format[Log[n_]/Log[10]] := Defer @ Log10[n]
Format[Log[n_]/Log[b_]] := Defer @ Log[b, n]

Protect[Times];
```

These assignments are made to a special class of rules: [`FormatValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules.html#SA.5.3).  Because these are only used in formatting this should not slow down internal operations using `Times`, unlike overloading `UpValues` or `DownValues`.

Each method relies on [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Defer.html) to prevent an infinite recursion yet allow evaluation of output when it is given as input.

Result:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What about `(Log[17] + Log[4])/Log[10]`?

Comment: @Sjoerd I'm not attempting that kind of operation but `Simplify` takes care of that particular case.

Comment: I know that, of course. The point that I wanted to make is that the precise configuration of Logs that you want to replace will more often than not be hidden somewhere in the structure of your output. Your current answer falls short of handling that.

Comment: @Sjoerd That's true.  Nevertheless it makes for cleaner output in many cases.  I am open to improvements. :-)

Comment: I have the solution but the margin of my laptop is too small to  contain it.

Answer (score 4):

Using a trick similar to what Chip showed in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101964):

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog" -> False];

logRule = Log[x_]/Log[b_] :> Switch[b, 2, Log2[x], 10, Log10[x], _, Log[b, x]];

{Log[17]/Log[2], Log[13]/Log[10], Log[99]/Log[11]} /. logRule
   {Log2[17], Log10[13], Log[11, 99]}
```

Sjoerd's example in a comment to the Wizard's answer requires some finesse:

```
Expand[(Log[17] + Log[4])/Log[10]] /. logRule
   Log10[4] + Log10[17]
```