# Transforming expressions in terms of Csc and Sec to expressions in terms of Sin and Cos

Tags: output-formatting, trigonometry

I am writing a code to compute some matrix quantities. The result involves `Sec` and`Csc` functions, and I want a form displayng *only* `Sin`and `Cos`. I have already seen [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7799/mathematica-sec-and-csc), but the solution suggested does not solve my problem, since I get the following:

```
    Ef = {{-Sin[ζ], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[ζ], 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, Cos[ζ], 0, 0, 0, 
0, γ Cos[ζ]}, {0, 0, 0, Sin[ζ], 0, 
0, -γ Sin[ζ], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -1/Sin[ζ], 0, 0,
 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/Cos[ζ], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, (1/Cos[ζ]), 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/Sin[ζ]}};

    G = Transpose[Ef].Ef;
    MatrixForm[G]

    ginv = Table[G[[i]][[j]], {i, 5, 8}, {j, 5, 8}];
    g = Inverse[ginv];
    MatrixForm[g] // FullSimplify
```

$$g= \begin{pmatrix} \sin ^2(\zeta ) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \cos ^2(\zeta ) & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{\csc ^2(\zeta )}{\gamma ^2+4 \csc ^2(2 \zeta
   )} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{\sec ^2(\zeta )}{\gamma ^2+4 \csc ^2(2
   \zeta )}\end{pmatrix}$$

But I would like the equivalent form (but easier to cope with),

$$g = \begin{pmatrix} \sin ^2(\zeta ) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \cos ^2(\zeta ) & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{\cos ^2(\zeta )}{1+\gamma ^2 \sin^2 (\zeta) \cos^2 (\zeta)} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{\sin ^2(\zeta )}{1+\gamma ^2 \sin^2 (\zeta) \cos^2 (\zeta)}\end{pmatrix}$$

Using

```
    $PrePrint = # /. {Csc[z_] :> 1/Defer@Sin[z], 
 Sec[z_] :> 1/Defer@Cos[z]} &;
```

I just manage to obtain terms like
$$ \frac{1}{\cos^2 (\zeta) \left( \gamma^2 + \frac{4}{\sin^2(2\zeta)}\right)}$$

and further `TrigExpand` does not have any effect.
Someone has any suggestion?

Comment: I feel your pain, but I'm afraid, no amount of `TrigExpand` will ever convert the last expression. It is a case of `a/a != 1` as it may be the case, that `a == 0`.

Comment: Although the goal here is a little different, I think the main issue is the same as in [Mathematica Sec and Csc](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7799/mathematica-sec-and-csc), and there probably isn't a better solution - I would love to be wrong, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have some success with specifying a different complexity function for `FullSimplify`. The following statement e.g. will avoid introducing `Sec` and `Csc`:

```
FullSimplify[g, ComplexityFunction->(Count[{#}, (Sec|Csc)[__]]&)]
```

Alas, the output might still not be exactly what you are after:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \sin ^2(\zeta ) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \cos ^2(\zeta ) & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{8 \cos ^2(\zeta )}{-\cos (4 \zeta ) \gamma ^2+\gamma ^2+8} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{8 \sin ^2(\zeta )}{-\cos (4 \zeta ) \gamma ^2+\gamma ^2+8} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$