# Prevent manipulations in PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, legending

[image]

Mathematica code to reproduce:

```
LogPlot[{x^(4/3), x*E^Sqrt[8Log2[5/2]*Log2[x]],x^2,x^(3/2), x*Log2[x]^2}, {x,10,1000000},  
 PlotLegends->LineLegend["Expressions",LegendMarkers->Automatic]]
```

How can I prevent the equations from having their form modified?

It would also be nice if I could get `Log2[x]` to appear as $\log_2x$.

**Note:** I want to avoid having a second copy of the expressions in the input.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7741/57

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel the following satisfies your three requirements of 1) having the labels unevaluated, 2) logs in `TraditionalForm`, and 3) functions specified only once:

```
funs = 
  Function[{expr}, Extract[expr, {1, #}, HoldForm] & /@ Range[Length[expr[[1]] ] ] ]@
   Hold[
     {x^(4/3), x*E^Sqrt[8 Log2[5/2]*Log2[x]], x^2, x^(3/2), x*Log2[x]^2}
   ];

LogPlot[funs // ReleaseHold // Evaluate, {x, 10, 1000000}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[TraditionalForm /@ funs, LegendMarkers -> Automatic]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Good idea to use `Hold` (+1). My answer is more boring and I don't actually have a way to test it...

Comment: @Jens Thanks! The basic idea came pretty soon, but it took quite a bit of fiddling before it all worked. Afterwards it looks so simple.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your main goal is to have the base-two logarithm displayed in a more readable form in the legend while at the same time being recognized as `Log2` in the first argument of the `Plot` command. Since labels and legends in plots are by default displayed in `TraditionalForm`, one can try to use this as a trigger to force the different display without having to enter two differently formatted versions for `Log2`.

However, since I don't think it's worth fiddling with protected names to modify the system behavior, I would instead recommend defining a custom function that looks like the base-two logarithm for the purpose of plot evaluations and displays the way you want in the legend. I don't want to mess with the built-in formatting of the `Log2` function directly.

I'll call that new binary log `ld` and define it to be equal to the `Log2` function, but only for numerical arguments (which is what you need when plotting). Then I make a separate definition for how `ld` is supposed to be formatted when `TraditionalForm` display is called for:

```
Clear[ld, x]

ld[x_?NumericQ] := Log2[x]

ld /: MakeBoxes[ld[x_], TraditionalForm] := 
 RowBox[{SubscriptBox["log", 2], "(", ToBoxes[x], ")"}]
```

The last line contains the formatting. Here is a test for numerical and symbolic arguments of `ld`:

```
ld[3]

(* ==> Log[3]/Log[2] *)

ld[x]

(* ==> ld[x] *)

ld[x] // TraditionalForm
```

> $\log_2(x)$

**Edit**

Sjoerd's simultaneous answer reminded me that I didn't say anything about how to put this into the plot. Well, I don't actually have version 9 installed here, but I would expect that it should work if you just replace `Log2` by `ld` everywhere in your plot command.