# How can I get Mathematica to simplify my expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
4.`*^-12 Sqrt[3.0254210421890627`*^22 - 6.25`*^22 T6^2]
```

The above expression is equal to

```
Sqrt[0.48406736675024997` - T6^2]
```

How can I tell *Mathematica* to simplify the first form into the second form?

Comment: Try `FullSimplify[MapAt[Factor, yourExpression, {2, 1}]]`.

Comment: @Silvia. Actually `FullSimplify` isn't needed; `Simplify` will do.

Comment: @m_goldberg Yes indeed. It's just my personal habit to use `FullSimplify`.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Silvia's comment:

```
expr = 4.`*^-12 Sqrt[3.0254210421890627`*^22 - 6.25`*^22 T6^2];

Rationalize[Factor //@ expr, 0] // Simplify
```

> ```
> Sqrt[1936269467001/4000000000000 - T6^2]
> ```

```
% // N
```

> ```
> Sqrt[0.484067 - 1. T6^2]
> ```

The `1.` is an artifact of `//  N` due to `- T6^2` being internally `Times[-1, Power[T6, 2]]`.

Comment: Note: with V9, `Rationalize` isn't needed: `Factor //@ expr // Simplify` will do.

Comment: This does not work for  2. Sqrt[0.25 - b/3] . I just want all things are within Sqrt.

Comment: @goodluck try: `Rationalize[2. Sqrt[0.25 - b/3], 0] // FullSimplify`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, it works for  0.25, but not work for 0.26.

Comment: @goodluck Is this a formatting issue?  You are aware that `Sqrt[9 x]` will automatically simplify to `3 Sqrt[x]`, correct?  Do you want a formatting rule [like this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7741/121)?