# Trouble with using a log10 function in NonlinearModelFit

Tags: fitting

I was wondering why won't mathematica give a result where the function is also `Log10`, instead it gives the ordinary `Log`. Is it because the `Log` fits the problem better than the `Log10` or... ?

```
Clear[x, a, b, c, d]

Data = {{0, 0}, {1, 6.91}, {2, 9.2}, {3, 11.4}, {4, 13.4}, {24, 
    39}, {25, 40.5}};

aa = NonlinearModelFit[Data, {a + b*Log10[c*x + d], c > 0, d > 0}, {a, b, c, d}, x];

aa // Normal

Show[Plot[aa[x], {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All], ListPlot[Data, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]]]]
```

Comment: Just type Log10[x] on a line and execute. What do you see?

Comment: Please see: [Display Log with desired notation in output](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7741)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The natural logarithm *is* the logarithm of mathematics. Hence, that's what *Mathematica* will use in results where a logarithm is present.

You can transform the expression if you really need to "see" things using common log, e.g. (*many* ways to do this, and see *Rahul*'s comment on an equivalent result...):

```
Replace[Normal@aa, Log[val_] :> Defer[Log10[val^Log[10]]], Infinity]
```

Comment: I feel `Log[val_] :> Log[10] Defer[Log10[val]]` is more what is desired: $-75.4281+47.393 \log _{10}(9.28813 x+41.0739)$ rather than $-75.4281+20.5825 \log _{10}\left((9.28813 x+41.0739)^{\log 10}\right)$.

Comment: @RahulNarain: You're probably right, since they're equivalent I suppose it depends where one wants the `Log[10]` to appear...

Comment: @RahulNarain: Um, I agree with you, had already updated my answer to point to your comment...

Comment: Thank you both for your contribution. The result is now displayed with a log10, which is what I originaly expected from Mathematica, but didn't get.