# How do I convert the E^[...] notation back to Exp[...] notation?

Tags: output-formatting, symbolic, expression-manipulation

How do I convert the `E^[...]` notation back to `Exp[...]` notation? Is there a simple command for this? It appears that `E^[...]` notation cannot be used as a name of an built-in function, but `Exp` is a valid name of a function.

Comment: You can use [esc]ee[esc] for the exponential E. For the problem at hand see ReplaceAll.

Comment: A code using ReplaceAll that does what I want will be appreciated. I am currently making do with the clumsy hack viz. ExpToTrig and referring to Sin and Cos as bonafide function names for further manipulation..

Comment: I just tried replacing e^{..} with Exp[..] using ReplaceAll or /. which is the same thing. It does not seem to work if   "..." is a lengthy symbolic expression.

Comment: One might expect that `E^(3 x) /. E^z_ -> Exp[z]` would return `Exp[3 x]`, but it does not, because, Mathematica always expresses `Exp[3 x]` as  `E^(3 x)` in lines of output.  Now, `E^(3 x) /. E^z_ -> HoldForm[Exp[z]]` will return `Exp[z]`  as output, but this may not be particularly useful, because `Exp[z]`  remains enclosed by `HoldForm`, even though it is not visible in the output.  I suggest you just live with `E^(3 x)`.  If you cannot for some reason, explain that reason in your question to obtain a better answer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Substituting `Defer` for `HoldForm` in your replacement may be more useful.  Good summary otherwise.  (see related [(7741)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7741/121))

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks. I need this because: Some clever user has written a subroutine called ApplyToArgument which applies a command such as Simplify, Expand etc. to the argument of a function. Both these pieces of information are to be supplied eg. ApplyToArgument[expr, Exp, Expand].  There seems to be a bug in this subroutine I suspect has something to do with the question I asked to begin with. This works wonderfully if the function in question is Sin,Cos, Log but does not seem to work  for Exp. I can of course use ExpToTrig and then use this routine but this is clumsy.

Comment: @Quasar, if the situation is like that, then this is an XY problem. The better solution would have been to add a rule for handling `Power[]`.

Comment: @J.M surely it's not impossible to override the default built in replacements?

Comment: Certainly not impossible, @LLlAMnYP; I was just making the point that the OP seems to be solving a more complicated problem than what s/he actually has.

Comment: Thanks to @Mr.Wizard, the following appears to answer the question:  For instance, `g = 4 Exp[3 (x + 2)] + 1` returns `1 + 4 E^(3 (2 + x))`, but `g /. Power[E, z_] -> Defer[Exp[z]]` returns it to its input form, `1 + 4 Exp[3 (2 + x)]`, and this result can be used directly in `ApplyToArgument`, if I understand this user function correctly.  However, some minor change to `ApplyToArgument` itself may be more effective, and I suggest that this user function be added to the question.

Comment: I got it from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064438/how-to-simplify-expand-apply-a-pattern-to-a-functions-argument

Answer (score 1):

@quasar  The subroutine "ApplyToArgument" that is being discussed here only applies to those mathematica commands that do not change form on simple execution for a variable argument, for example Sin[x] remains as Sin[x], Log[x] remains as Log[x] and so on. But Exp[x] becomes e^x, Simplify[x] becomes x and for such cases it won't work.

Specifically for the case of "Exp" the following subroutine will work instead.

```
ApplyToArgument[expr_, ToWhat_, WhatFunction_] := 
 Module[{list}, list = Extract[expr, Position[expr, ToWhat[_]]];
  list = Map[Rule[#, ToWhat[WhatFunction[#[[2]]]]] &, list];
  Return[expr /. list]]
```

Comment: Great work Joy.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is apparently an XY problem, let me provide a solution for problem X instead of the Y being asked here:

```
ata[expr_, ToWhat_, WhatFunction_] := 
    expr /. HoldPattern[ToWhat[x__]] :> ToWhat[Apply[Sequence, WhatFunction /@ {x}]]
```

Now, for example:

```
ata[Sin[a b + a c] + (u + v)/(f p + f q), Sin, Simplify]
   (u + v)/(f p + f q) + Sin[a (b + c)]

ata[Sin[a b + a c] + (u + v)/(f p + f q), Power, Simplify]
   (u + v)/(f (p + q)) + Sin[a b + a c]    

ata[4 Exp[3 (x + 2)] + 1, Power, Expand]
   1 + 4 E^(6 + 3 x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is not defined well. What is e^{...}? Do you mean `E^2` for instance? Or you actually mean `e^{2}? I'm going with the latter.

First, we need to define `e` to be the Euler number by setting it equal to `E`. Since anything in `{...}` is a list *and* many Mathematica functions such as `Exp` are distributive (i.e. `F[{a, b, c}] = {F[a], F[b], F[c]}`) we can write

```
e = E;
First[e^{2}]
FullForm[First[e^{2}]]
```

This gives you `Power[E, 2]`. This is the same as `Exp[2]`. If you want the expression `Exp[2]` verbatim, you have to use `Hold` or `Unevaluated`.

Comment: Sir, I know all this but please tell me the answer to my question.

Comment: Oooh, I see what you are asking. I'll update my answer soon. So you want "e^{2}" to give you Exp[2]? Is the input an string? If so I can help you. Otherwise, we can't change Mathematica syntax.